# Как исправить ошибку "Использование локальной переменной, которой не присвоено значение"?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Даже если я ввожу значение переменной заранее, оно мне выдаёт предупреждение: Переменной "speed" присвоено значение, но оно ни разу не использовано. Ошибка в строке float speed = speed * 0.75f;
Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    float horAxis;
    public float speed;
    Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    bool isGrounded;
    int jumps;
    public Vector2 jumpForce;
    void Start()
    {
        isGrounded = true;
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        horAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if(isGrounded == true)
        {
            jumps = 1;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            float speed = speed * 0.75f;
        }
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(horAxis * speed, rb2d.velocity.y);
        if (jumps == 1 && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            isGrounded = false;
            rb2d.AddForce(jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Force);
            jumps = 0;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А для чего менять скорость, умножая на себя же скорость и на 0.75? И ещё на левый контрол? Ускорение?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`float speed` - объявление новой переменной с указанным именем и типом

`speed` - использование уже объявленной переменной

Видимо надо `speed = speed * 0.75f;`

Answer (score 3):

```cs
float speed = speed * 0.75f;
```

Тут объявили новую локальную переменную, и не использовали её.

Создавая её в `Update` вы могли бы использовать её только там, поэтому обращаясь к `speed` в другом месте вы бы обращались не к данной переменной а к полю `speed` где переменная объявлялась.

От этого и выходит что данная переменная никогда и ни кем не использовалась.

Решение:

```
speed = speed * 0.75f
```

либо

```
speed *= 0.75f
```